# How can I catch and do something when user focused on input, and when he lost focus?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have input fields in my app, and I want to do something when user focused on input(for example clicked input), and do something when user lost focus(for example clicked other field or clicked some button).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onFocus` event for input focus and `onBlur` event for focus out.

```
<input
   type="text"
   onFocus={() => {
       // logic on input focus
   }}
   onBlur={() => {
       // logic on focusout
   }}
/>
```

Comment: I know about these events, but look, what happens. I refresh the page, and on console are logged 4 logs. And then nothing logs.
onBlur
onFocus
onBlur
onFocus

Comment: I guess then something wrong with your class component and state management.

Comment: @ClueMediator  
I am new here, I can't write code in a comment. I use 
```
```
but it doesn't work

Comment: You made mistake with event binding. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Can you please mark an answer as accepted? So it will be helpful to others as well. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can using `onFocus` when user focus to input and `onBlur` when user focus outside input

```
<input
   {...props}
   onFocus={() => console.log('focused')}
   onBlur={() => console.log('blur')}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply onFocus and onBlur into your input field.
 Example :

```
<input onFocus = {() => console.log('focus')}  onBlur={() => console.log('blur')}  type='text' value="xyz" />
```